# How to use group by to get a list of new column in an entity

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have Answer entity which has values like this

```
question answer 
1           x
2           y
3           z
4           p
1           x
2           q
3           r
```

I need to get answers group by questions

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
<1, [x,x]
 2, [y,p]
 3, [z,r]
 4, [p]>
```

I could get `List<Answer>` like this

```
Map<Integer, List<Answer>> collect = answers
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Answer::getQuestion));
```

but I can't find a way to get it as `List<String>` rather than `List<Answer>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = answers
         .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Answer::getQuestion,
                Collectors.mapping(Answer::getAnswerAsString, Collectors.toList())       
));
```

just replace `getAnswerAsString` with whatever method you have that gets you that String from `Answer`.

Answer (score 3):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = answers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Answer::getQuestion, 
        Collectors.mapping(Answer::getAnswer, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: If you down vote my answer please add a comment explaining the reason?